# Application slow on Startup

Tags: c#, startup

I have developed an Application using C# and wpf. I also have used a cloud. So while creating an EXE, I am using the windows installer(msi). But because of this the Application is taking a long time to start up on a non-admin user. It takes about 7 minutes to start where as for an Admin user it hardly takes about 10 seconds.

As far as I have searched, the non-admin need to check access to files and also copy them in the local folder and then it starts. But can someone please explain a little better? and also give some suggestions for a quick startup on the non-admin user.

Comment: I don't see how Windows Installer (.MSI) could have anything to do with this.  The is an application design / profiling / performance issue.  We would have to look at the source code of your EXE to understand what it is doing and why it takes so long.

Comment: Does it take this long the second time you start it up?

Comment: I agree @ChristopherPainter. So what exactly should i be looking for?

Comment: yes @JoelCoehoorn it takes the time to start up, but then it works fine.

Comment: Hmm... I see this: "`The non-admin need to check access to files.`" Skip the check. Just try to copy, and then handle the exception if this fails. It could be that the check is causing you to wait while something times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this MSDN Aricle may help you.

[Improving Application Startup Time by Claudio Caldato](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163655.aspx)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because the link target may change or go away.